# c++ mortgage loan calculator

Tags: c++, math, calculator

I am fairly new in C++ and I have encountered some trouble. For this, I am trying to create a mortgage calculator. The issue that I am having is that it is not printing out the correct amounts for monthly payment and total pay back. This is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main () {

    double annualInterestRate(0); // yearly interest rate
    double loanAmount(0); // the amount of the loan
    double monthlyInterestRate(0); // interest rate amount monthly
    double numberofPayments(0); // the amount of payments
    double totalYearsToRepay(0); // years needed to payback
    double totalPayBack(0); // total amount being paid back
    double monthlyPayment(0); 

    while (true) {

        cout << "Enter the amount of the loan:";
        cin >> loanAmount;

        cout << "Enter annual interest rate in decimal term (example 0.075):";
        cin >> annualInterestRate;

        cout << "Enter the length of the loan in years:";
        cin >> totalYearsToRepay;

        loanAmount = loanAmount;

        cout << "loanAmount: $" << setprecision(2) << fixed << loanAmount << endl;

        annualInterestRate = annualInterestRate;

        cout << "annualInterestRate: $" << setprecision(5) << fixed << annualInterestRate << endl;

        cout << "totalYearsToRepay: " << setprecision(0) << fixed << totalYearsToRepay << endl;

        // find monthly interest rate.
        monthlyInterestRate=annualInterestRate / 12;

        totalYearsToRepay = totalYearsToRepay;

        numberofPayments = totalYearsToRepay* 12;

        monthlyPayment = (loanAmount * (monthlyInterestRate) * totalYearsToRepay) / (totalYearsToRepay-1);

        cout << "Monthly Payment: $" << setprecision(2) << fixed << monthlyPayment << endl;

        totalPayBack = (monthlyPayment) * (numberofPayments);

        cout << "Total Pay Back: $" << setprecision (2) << fixed << totalPayBack << endl;

    }
}
```

This is an example of what should be printed:

```
Loan Amount: $50000.00
Annual Interest Rate: 0.06250 
Years to repay: 10
Monthly Payment: $561.40 
Total Pay Back: $67368.06
```

I am not getting the monthly payment and total pay back. I don't know what is wrong with the math portion. Please help! The given formula is `monthly payment= loanAmount * monthlyInterestRate * powerFactor / powerFactor -1` where `powerFactor = (1+monthlyInterestRate)^numberofpayments`
.

Comment: What are you getting? Show the output.

Comment: OT: Statements like this: `loanAmount = loanAmount;`  do nothing.

Comment: My advice is to figure out the math first with paper and pen before you write any code.

Comment: That's what I've been trying to do and I haven't been able to figure it out. This is what I am getting:                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
loanAmount: $250000.00
annualInterestRate: $0.04750
totalYearsToRepay: 30
Monthly Payment: $1023.71
Total Pay Back: $368534.48

Comment: What @drescherjm said....clearly the math is wrong.  seems there should be a `pow` in there somewhere...

Comment: The formula given was: monthly payment = loanAmount * monthly interest rate * powerFactor / powerFactor - 1 where powerFactor = (1+ monthly interest rate) ^ number of payments

Comment: Which is different from what you typed. Although note that in `c++` ^ means exclusive or so be careful. You need pow() instead of ^

Comment: What do you mean by needing pow()? would I have to do powerFactor = (1+ monthly interest rate) pow(number of payments) and leave the other formula as it is ? @drescherjm

Comment: The math formula: `powerFactor = (1+ monthly interest rate) ^ number of payments` would translate to `powerFactor = pow(1.0 + monthlyInterestRate,numberofPayments);` in c++ based on the documentation: [http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/)

Comment: Yes thank you! That is how I have it but now I am getting errors for the monthly payment formula. I have it as monthly payment = loanAmount * monthlyInterestRate * powerFactor / powerFactor - 1 and it is saying "Reference to overloaded function could not be resolved; did you mean to call it?" @drescherjm

Answer (score 0):

I would use this formula stated here https://www.thecalculatorsite.com/articles/finance/compound-interest-formula.php

and then I would divide the A value by the number of months the person has to pay off this total price called A in the formula.

You are looking for what is called "compound interest rate".

Comment: Thank you! I tried that but it was not giving me the amounts that I should be getting for monthlyPayment and totalPayBack

Answer (score 0):

In the posted code there's this line

```
monthlyPayment = (loanAmount * (monthlyInterestRate) * totalYearsToRepay)
               / (totalYearsToRepay-1);
```

In the comments, the OP clearify

> The formula given was:
>   monthly payment = loanAmount * monthly interest rate * powerFactor / powerFactor - 1
>   where
>   powerFactor = (1+ monthly interest rate) ^ number of payments

That could be translated into those C++ lines of code:

```
double powerFactor = std::pow(1.0 + monthlyInterestRate, numberofPayments);
double monthlyPayment = loanAmount * monthlyInterestRate * powerFactor
                      / (powerFactor - 1.0);
//  The parenthesis, here, are needed, due to standard math operator precedence
```

It's worth noting that the code contains other issues, like variables assigned to themselves or the never ending loop

```
while (true)
{
    // Put a break statement somewhere or change the condition
}
```